# como saber si un numero ingresado por el usuario, pertenece o no a una serie

Tags: c++

la serie que tengo es 0, 0, 1, 4, 11, 26, 57, 120, 247,?, se como hacer para saber la serie determinando un termino pero no se cual seria la modificacion si quiero saber si por ejemplo 3 pertenece a la serie o no. intente ponerle un mientras para que se pueda incrementar t con una bandera, pero no resulto en algunos puntos me funcionaba para 4 y 0 pero no para 1 o viseversa

este es mi codigo en pseint para determinar la serie mediante un termino

Algoritmo Punto_12

```
//0, 0, 1, 4, 11, 26, 57, 120, 247,?

Definir t, i, n, s Como Entero

Escribir "ingrese un numero"

leer t

s<-0

si t>=2 Entonces

    t<-t-2

    Para i<-0 Hasta t Con Paso 1 Hacer

        s<-2*s+i

    FinPara

FinSi

Escribir "la serie es ", s

FinAlgoritmo
```

Este es mi codigo en c++

```
#include (iostream)

#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

main()

{int t,i,s,n;

    //SERIE 0, 0, 1, 4, 11, 26, 57, 120, 247,?

    cout << "Ingrese un numero" << endl;

    cin >> n;

    s=0;

    t=1;

    if (t>=1)

    {

        t=t-2;

        for(i=0;i<=t;i++)

        {

            s=2*s+1;

            if (n==s)

                cout << "Pertenece a la serie" << endl;

            else

                cout << "No pertenece a la serie" << endl;

            t++;

        }
    }

    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la serie sea ascendente, deberás comprobar si el número buscado es igual al término de la serie hasta que el número sea mayor al término. No se cómo generar la serie que muestras así que te pongo un ejemplo con la secuencia de Fibonacci:

```
int numero;
std::cout << "Numero a comprobar: ";
std::cin >> numero;

bool encontrado = false;
for (int a = 0, b = 1, i = 0; a < numero; ++i)
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Mientras el término de la serie
//                                           sea menor al número a comprobar
{
    if ((encontrado = (numero == a)))
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Si el número es igual al término, acabamos
        break;

    int c = a + b;
    std::cout << c << ' ';

    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVAxboQwEKztV4ycAhAXKWkoOCA/yAuuMcZEVmCNjKlO93ayJskpl8a7OxrvzKxZlmczafrY9ydHZtoGi8b5NQar505KRxGzdpQX8ipFmmibbfBnKdY41LXxW0TTQL0fMDSMn5fgex1qqDvLEbru/lWK3vsJloynGPTg0WLU02qZP/qAPOloBl9O6Lm8nuDSdGaw@d2CsnSFFOxKuBF5/rAt/yahbaGLgmlC9JzoM2kfKQyTNEr0LPmYxKQnQ3ZQk4mDkmwYbm7yX/DsQlmqP4Lc/XXyBqXAhwB5VRx3wmJDtGSNZf1JY7XB2QupJBds3AJxTnnb96qq5Bc)</kbd>.

Comment: hola en mi descripción hay dos códigos el primero de la serie 0, 0,  1,  4, 11, 26, ? Funciona asi yo quiero saber el término 1 en "ingrese un número" yo pongo 1 y me devuelve 0 que es el primer término, si yo quiero saber el término 4 me devuelve 4 que es el término 4 en la serie. La cuestión está en como automatizar el término en el primer código sería la variable y pueda incluir una variable "num" que tenga cualquier número y verificar si se encuentra o no en la serie

Comment: "*¿Cómo automatizar el término en el primer código sería la variable y pueda incluir una variable "num" que tenga cualquier número y verificar si se encuentra o no en la serie?*" eso es precisamente lo que hace el código de ejemplo que he compartido. Si el número está en la serie, la variable `encontrado` será verdadera. Echa un vistazo al enlace que he puesto con el código funcionando.